# Is there way to use C++ 11 thread objects within Older C/C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I tried to construct a wrapper class for C++11 Thread class using VS2013(Platformtoolset v120)and Intel C++ Compiler 14(lastest build) and built it as a dll,and my purpose was to use respective libs and dlls with VS2010(Platfromtoolset v100),my pure intention was to somehow use thread object with VS2010 builds.Initially I guessed this cannot be achieved,but Is there any methodology accomplish it?
Please help
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pre-C++11 compilers / libraries, you can use the [Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html), from which the standard thread library comes from. You can either just use `boost::thread` directly, regardless of whether there is C++11 support or not. Or you can conditionally switch between the two. For that, you can use this technique:

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>

#ifdef BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_THREAD

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

namespace my_lib {

using boost::thread;

// .. using anything else you need, like boost::mutex

}

#else

#include <thread>

namespace my_lib {

using std::thread;

// .. using anything else you need, like std::mutex

}

#endif
```

Just put the above in your own header (e.g., `my_thread.hpp`), and use `my_lib::thread` in your code. You will have to watch out for a few incompatibilities, but that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I tried to develop my own lib without using "boost" lib,using C/C++ own thread class.